# How to test Apache Camel onCompletion().onFailureOnly() logic

Tags: java, apache-camel, integration-testing

Suppose I have Camel route like this:

```
@Component
public class MyRoute extends RouteBuilder {

  private final BrokenBean brokenBean;

  public MyRoute(BrokenBean brokenBean) {
    this.brokenBean = brokenBean;
  }

  @Override
  public void configure() throws Exception {
    from("{{rabbitmq.inbound}}")
        .errorHandler(defaultErrorHandler()
            .maximumRedeliveries(1)
            .redeliveryDelay(1000))
        .end()
        .onCompletion()
        .onCompleteOnly()
        .to("direct:success")
        .end()
        .onCompletion()
        .onFailureOnly()
        .to("direct:failure").id("failure")
        .end()
        .routeId("my_route")
        .bean(brokenBean, "hello")
        .to("direct:success").id("success");

    from("direct:success")
        .log("Success received");

    from("direct:failure")
        .log("Failed received");
  }
```

And here is bean logic which is called from this route.
This is just an example.

```
@Component
public class BrokenBean {

  public void hello() {
    System.out.println("Hello called");
  }
}
```

As route logic reveals and I tested it manually, if we got the exception
from BrokeBean the message would be routed to `direct:failure` and it does in runtime.

But in test below:

```
@RunWith(CamelSpringBootRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = MyRouteTest.TestConfig.class)
public class MyRouteTest {

  @Produce("direct:inbound")
  protected ProducerTemplate directInbound;

  @Autowired
  SpringCamelContext context;

  @MockBean
  BrokenBean brokenBeanMock;

  @Before
  public void setUp() throws Exception {
    AdviceWith.adviceWith(context.getRouteDefinition("my_route"),
        context,
        new AdviceWithRouteBuilder() {
          @Override
          public void configure() throws Exception {

            onException(RuntimeException.class)
                .continued(true);

            weaveById("failure").replace().to("mock:direct:failure");
            weaveById("success").replace().to("mock:direct:success");
          }
        });
  }

  @Test
  public void testMyRouteFailedSuccessExpected() throws Exception {

    MockEndpoint mockEndpoint = context.getEndpoint("mock:direct:failure",
        MockEndpoint.class);

    doThrow(new RuntimeException("Failed call")).when(brokenBeanMock).hello();

    directInbound.sendBody("hello there");

    mockEndpoint.expectedMessageCount(1);
    mockEndpoint.assertIsSatisfied();
  }

  @Test
  public void testMyRouteSuccessFailedExpected() throws Exception {

    MockEndpoint mockEndpoint = context.getEndpoint("mock:direct:success",
        MockEndpoint.class);

    doThrow(new RuntimeException("Failed call")).when(brokenBeanMock).hello();

    directInbound.sendBody("hello there");

    mockEndpoint.expectedMessageCount(1);
    mockEndpoint.assertIsSatisfied();
  }


  @Configuration
  @Import({MyRoute.class})
  public static class TestConfig extends CamelConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public BridgePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer bridgePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer() {
      final YamlPropertiesFactoryBean yaml = new YamlPropertiesFactoryBean();
      final BridgePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer configurer = new BridgePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer();
      yaml.setResources(new ClassPathResource("application.yml"));
      configurer.setOrder(1);
      configurer.setIgnoreUnresolvablePlaceholders(true);
      configurer.setProperties(yaml.getObject());
      return configurer;
    }
  }
}
```

I have the opposite result: `testMyRouteSuccessFailedExpected` succeeded and `testMyRouteFailedSuccessExpected` failed.
Which is not what I expected. Actually I tried a lot with adviceWith setup but with no luck.
It seems a simple case to check but behaviour look strange to me.
Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can essentially only use 1 `onCompletion` in a route. You have 2. However we don't validate this on startup and report a problem.

Camel cannot understand that your 2 on completions would not overlap as one is for success and another for failure. So you need to only use 1 in your route.

Comment: Can you please clarify, why it should overlap as I differentiate them by the result outcome of the completion putting `onCompleteOnly` and `onFailureOnly` in each branch ? Actually, it works as I expect. Why I write like this is because as I discovered in case when retry is in place and then suddenly it succeeded the `onCompleteOnly` will be fired, otherwise after all failed retries `onFailureOnly` will take place this is what I need, not in this example but generally.